# Why do some elements of the array are missing when I copy them?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I would like to merge two arrays in one ,then choose random elements from the array but some elements are missing when I display the result.

```
Number_set = 0:9;
alpha_set = 'a':'z';
Number_setc = num2str(Number_set);
merged=append(alpha_set,Number_setc);
pw=char([1,5]);
for i=1:5
ind=randi(length(merged));
pw(i)=merged(ind); %pw is the result
end
```

Comment: Did you look at the values of the intermediate variables you are creating? Do they match your expectations? -- For starters, I would build `Number_setc` as `'0':'9'`.

Comment: Unfortunately Number_set is given, and when I add the two arrays the `merged` array looks like this: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9' .Maybe it copys the space and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Comment: `num2str` does that. You could convert to char using `char(Number_set + '0')`.

Comment: finally `merged = regexprep(merged, '\s', '')` helped, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: Bringing regular expressions into this is overkill. You can remove spaces by `merged(merged==' ') = []`. But I would do simply `merged = [alpha_set, char(Number_set + '0')]`. The rest of the code can be replaced by `pw = merged(randi(numel(merged), 1, 5))`.